# Resizing items which are rotated css

Tags: html, css

Wondering if someone can help.

I'm a beginner learning website development and have been playing around with different styles for a particular project. The one I'm trying at the moment has a background colour, on top of this is a central wrapper of 60% width which contains all the website gumph. on the sides of the wrapper I have text turned 90/270 running down the wrapper with the website name.

When I go to resize the website the text jumps, how do I get the text to stay in it's original position? Also a secondary question, the text I have put as a % in CSS, however it doesn't seem to resize with the screen, even if I try em, here is the css:

```
*{
                                                                        background-color:#085C08;
max-width:100%;   
    max-height:100%;   
    min-width:200px;     
    margin:0 auto;
    }

.wrapper{
    width: 60%;    
    background-color: #FDF3EC;    
    margin:0 auto;    
    margin-top:-1%;    
    margin-bottom:-1.5%;     
    }

.artwork-r{
    transform:rotate(90deg);   
    white-space:nowrap;   
    transform-origin:bottom;   
    margin-top:-52.5%;    
    margin-left:78.65%;   
    position:absolute;    
    width:0%;    
    height:0%;    
    clear:both;        
    }

.artwork-r p{
    padding:0%;     
    font-size:490%;    
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;     
    color:#FDF3EC;     
    }

.artwork-l{
    transform:rotate(270deg);     
    white-space:nowrap;    
    transform-origin:top left;    
    margin-left:15.1%;    
    margin-top:0.4%;    
    position:absolute;      
    width:0%;     
    height:0%;     
    clear:both;      
    }

.artwork-l p{
    padding:0%;     
    font-size:490%;     
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;     
    color:#FDF3EC;     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

when position the text, don't use `margin-left` or `margin-top`, those will change as the screen size changes. You should use `top`, `bottom`, `left` and/or `right`.

For the font size, em's and % are both based **NOT** on the screen size, but instead it's parent's font size. Without seeing your markup I am not 100% sure, but you will probably want the position of `.artwork-l` to be set as `right: 100%;`